# Find $k$,$m$,$n$ such that $f$ is an epimorphism/monomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to solve this task: 
$f \in L(X,Y)$, $\dim X = n$, $\dim Y = m$, $\dim ker(f) = k.$ 
Find $k$,$m$,$n$ such that: 
a) $f$ is an monomorphism 
b) $f$ is an epimorphism

b) If $f$ is an epimorphism, we must be able to get any element from $Y$ by $f$. So $\dim y = \dim im(f)$
$$ m = n - k $$
have I right? 
a) But there I am not sure about my idea - I think that it should be (intuitively) $\dim X = \dim im(f) $ so I get:
$$ n = n - k $$
$$ k = 0 $$
but firstly I am not sure if that is true, secondly it is only my intuitive try...

Comment: $(b)$ is correct. What is a monomorphism? I don't see monomorphism anywhere online.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri The terms are defined in a general sense in category theory, but the exact definition one works with depends on the context.  For linear maps, $f$ is a monomorphism if and only if it is injective (one-to-one), and $f$ is an epimorphism if and only if it is surjective (onto).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks for the definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answers are correct.

The rank nullity theorem states that for linear maps $f: X \to Y$, $\dim \ker(f) + \dim \operatorname{im}(f) = \dim(X)$.  So for this context, we have $k+ \dim \operatorname{im}(f) = n$.

For a: whatever your definition of a monomorphism, we should be able to conclude that $f$ is a monomorphism if and only if $\ker(f) = \{0\}$, which is to say that $k=0$.  The rank-nullity theorem confirms your intuition.

For b: whatever your definition of an epimorphism, we should be able to conclude that $f$ is an epimorphism if and only if $\operatorname{im}(f) = Y$.  So, $\dim \operatorname{im}(f) = \dim Y$, and by the rank-nullity theorem $\dim \operatorname{im}(f) = n-k$.